# How to compute one column based off multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: tables]

[sql import file](http://www.filedropper.com/4-28-15test%20import.sql)

```
--sources (id, name)---
1, "source one"
2, "source two"
3, "source three"


--first_related_items (value, source_id) ---
0, 1    

--second_related_items (value, source_id) ---
0, 2
2, 3

--third_related_items (value, source_id) ---
1, 3
```

I have source rows and related items in multiple other tables. How do I get a computed column based off the other tables? The computed column would be for each row in source table. Like

```
 SELECT 
   sources.name as name, 
   COMPUTED_VALUE(
     first_related_items, 
     second_related_items, 
     third_related_items) as result 
 FROM sources
```

The computed column would be derived something like this

```
if(value for source row in first table == 0){
     return 0
}
else if(value for source row in second table == 0){
  if(value for source row in third table == 1){
    return 1
  } else {
    return 0
  }
} else if(value for source row in third table != NULL){
    return value for source row in third table
} else {
   return -1
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and desired results.  WIthout sample data, your pseudo-code doesn't make sense.  What, for instance, does "value in first table" mean?  Any value?  All values?  A particular value based on user input of some sort?

Comment: Can you elaborate on third table else? Do you comare to NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join all four tables and compute this column as a `case` expression:

```
SELECT    s.id,
          CASE WHEN fri.value = 0 THEN 0
               WHEN sri.value = 0 THEN CASE WHEN tri = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
               WHEN tri IS NOT NULL THEN tri
               ELSE -1
          END AS computed_value
FROM      sources s
LEFT JOIN first_related_items fri ON fri.source_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN second_related_items sri ON sri.source_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN third_related_items tri ON tri.source_id = s.id
```